# Unix Filename ignore list

Tags: filenames, filter

We are trying to set up Unix based server and we are trying to figure out if there is any way to forbid creating certain files on the server.

I mean files like: `.DS_Store`, `.BridgeCache`, `.BridgeCachet`, `.BridgeCacheT`, `.BridgeSort`, `._.BridgeCache`, `._.BridgeCacheT`, `Thumbs.db`, `.Parent`, `._TemporaryItems` & folders ike `.AppleDouble`, `.AppleDB`, `.AppleDesktop`, `.TemporaryItems`.

We thought about `cron` which would delete those files every night, but much better solution would be to completely disallow this files to exist on our server.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: How are you serving the files? Samba? NFS? Webdav?

Answer (score 2):

Which Unix? It will be quite difficult to make it so that file creation fails when an "invalid" name is passed to it, but there are some platform-specific ways of doing this.

First of all, there is `inotify` and its relatives, which can at least observe the filesystem and notify you immediately when a file is created. I'm not sure you can actually stop the creation and make the system call return an error, but you can get rid of it immediately.

Another way would be a fuse-based filesystem (pre-existing or newly written). In `fuse`, you actually implement all the filesystem procedures in user-space and you can make your own rules what a file is and how it may be called.

All this of course depends on whether you have a local filesystem, a remotely mounted system, some network transfer protocol?

This may be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588386/intercepting-file-system-system-calls